# Form with two sections - Javascript Validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form (below) with two sections. Each section contains its own fields. I need to make sure at least one section is **completely filled out** before the user can submit the form.  So if in Section 1, the User Email field is entered then Preferred Colors must also be filled-out and Section 2 is now optional.

Similarly, if section 2 has entered the User ID, then the Gender should also be checked. And now Section 1 now optional. How do I do this? My javascript logic is wrong below.

Submission Form - with two sections.

```
<script>
    function validate() 
{ 
    if ((document.frm.userID.value == "" && document.frm.UserEmail.value == "")) 
     { 
        if (document.frm.userID.value != "" && document.frm.UserEmail.value == "" || document.frm.userID.value == "" && document.frm.UserEmail.value != "") 
        { 
            return true; 
        }else 
        { 
            return false; 
        }  
    } 
   return( true ); 
}
</script>
<form action="#" id="frm" method="post" name="frm" onsubmit="return(validate())">

--------- Section 1 -----------
    User Email*:
    <input type="text" name="UserEmail">          

   <p><b>Preferred Color*:</b></p>
   <input type="radio" name="preferred_color" value="Red" /> Red<br />
   <input type="radio" name="preferred_color" value="Blue" /> Blue<br />
   <input type="radio" name="preferred_color" value="Green" /> Green<br />


 --------- Section 2 -----------
USER ID *:
 <input type="text" name="userID" value="">
GENDER*:
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female

<input type="submit" value="submit"> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning true if (all inputs in section 1 have a value) or (all inputs in section 2 have a value)

```
function validate() 
{
    var result = (document.frm.UserEmail.value != "" && document.frm.preferred_color.value != "")
       || (document.frm.userID.value != "" && document.frm.sex.value != "");
    return result;
}
```

UPDATE: If you want a more scalable solution, try using the code below (it requires jQuery). This way, if you add any new inputs to either section, they will automatically be checked by the validation function. Basically, what it does is loop through all form fields inside `section1` and `section2`, and make sure that each field has a value. Also note the addition of `<div id="section1">` and `<div id="section2">`.

```
<form action="#" id="frm" method="post" name="frm" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <div id="section1">
        User Email*: <input type="text" name="UserEmail" /><br />
        Preferred Color*:<br />

        <label><input type="radio" name="preferred_color" value="Blue" />Blue</label><br /> 
        <label><input type="radio" name="preferred_color" value="Green" />Green</label>

        <!--Newly Added requirement if and only if Green is selected-->
        <input type="checkbox" name="preferred_color_green" value="blackShoes">Green goes w black<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="preferred_color_green" value="favoriteColor">its my favorite color 

    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="section2">
        USER ID *:
        <input type="text" name="userID" value="" /><br />
        GENDER*:<br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />Male</label><br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />Female</label>

        <!--Newly Added requirement if and only if female is selected-->
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">buy a female bike<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">buy a smaller car 


    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
function validate() {
    // Valid if all fields in section1 OR section2 are entered
    return validateSection("section1") || validateSection("section2");
}
function validateSection(section) {
    var inputs = $("#" + section + " input, #" + section + " textarea, #" + section + " select");

    // Make sure each field has a value
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        if (input.type == "button" || input.type == "submit" || input.type == "checkbox") {
            // Ignore buttons and check boxes
            continue;
        }
        if (input.type == "radio") {
            // Handle radio buttons specially.
            // They will always have a value, just make sure one of them is checked.
            var items = document.frm.elements[input.name];
            var selected = false;
            for( var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                if (items[j].checked) {
                    selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!selected) {
               return false;
            }
        } else if (input.value == "") {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jsfu1uc/6/

Comment: I tried your updated version but doesn't seem to do anything. Looks  like a nice solutions as it will address possible issues when adding new fields. 

Also how can we let user know that a field is missing. Or add some text next to the missing input.

Comment: --UPDATE---
it doesn't work in Chrome browser :( 
in IE its validating UserEmail and userID. Its ignoring radio buttons and checkboxes.

Comment: Strange that it doesn't work for you in Chrome - it worked fine for me. I've updated the code to work in IE 11. Looks like `document.frm[input.name].value` doesn't work in IE. Also see my fiddle.

Comment: It **works now** with the change you've made. Is there a way to **alert** the user _which field is missing?_ Thanks again.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this; it depends on what the UI to look like. Common ways of doing this are displaying an error message after the required field, displaying an error summary near the submit button, or showing an `alert()`. In my updated fiddle, I've given an example of showing a message after the required field. http://jsfiddle.net/5jsfu1uc/11/

Comment: Also, depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to consider using 2 different submit buttons (and maybe 2 separate forms). I think it would make more sense from a user's perspective to have a separate button for each section.

Comment: I agree. Two submit buttons would be better but customer wants one submit button. BTW its working beautifully..i can't thank you enough.

Comment: Customer added a **new twist** to it. If one of the radio buttons is checked...user must also check at least one checkbox located below it. See updated form above. How can i handle that?

Comment: aj_r,I tried modifying your if stmt in your code to handle the checkboxes for my above  requirement but no joy.  `if (input.type == "radio" || input.type == "checkbox") {
var items = document.frm.elements[input.name];
var selected = false;
for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) { 
if (items[j].checked) {
if (items[j].value == "Green") {
alert("Green: you will need to check some checkboxes.");
                              return false;
                            } 
                            selected = true;
                   break;                        }
                    }`